# ROS 2 - Poincloud2 message drop when trying to display in RVIZ2

Tags: ros2, c++, pointcloud

I want to send a dummy PointCloud2 message to be visualized with RVIZ2, but when I try to subscribe to the pointCloud2 message, I received the following error :

[INFO] [1698326059.380456033] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame '625' at time 1698326054,377 for reason 'Unknown'

And I can't get rviz2 to show any frame, I populated every field of the pointcloud2 message.

The code to generate the pointCloud2 is the following :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp"

using std::placeholders::_1;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using namespace std::chrono;

class TestPcloud2Pub : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    TestPcloud2Pub() : Node("test_pcloud2_pub")
    {
        mPcloudMsg.height = 5;
        mPcloudMsg.width = 3;
        mPcloudMsg.is_dense = true;
        mPcloudMsg.is_bigendian = true;
        mPcloudMsg.point_step = 4 * 3;
        mPcloudMsg.row_step = mPcloudMsg.width * 4 * 3;

        std::vector<sensor_msgs::msg::PointField> pointFields;

        sensor_msgs::msg::PointField pointFieldX;
        pointFieldX.name = 'x';
        pointFieldX.offset = 0;
        pointFieldX.datatype = 7; // float 32
        pointFieldX.count = 1;

        sensor_msgs::msg::PointField pointFieldY;
        pointFieldY.name = 'y';
        pointFieldY.offset = 4;
        pointFieldY.datatype = 7; // float 32
        pointFieldY.count = 1;

        sensor_msgs::msg::PointField pointFieldZ;
        pointFieldZ.name = 'z';
        pointFieldZ.offset = 8;
        pointFieldZ.datatype = 7; // float 32
        pointFieldZ.count = 1;

        pointFields.push_back(pointFieldX);
        pointFields.push_back(pointFieldY);
        pointFields.push_back(pointFieldZ);

        mPcloudMsg.fields = pointFields;

        mPublisher = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>("test_pcloud", 10);
        mTimer = this->create_wall_timer(500ms, std::bind(&TestPcloud2Pub::timer_callback, this));
    }

private:
    void timer_callback()
    {
        mPcloudMsg.header.frame_id = std::to_string(mFrameCounter);

        auto tp = system_clock::now();
        auto tpSec = time_point_cast<seconds>(tp);
        nanoseconds ns = tp - tpSec;

        uint32_t timeSec = static_cast<uint32_t>(tpSec.time_since_epoch().count());
        uint32_t timeNsec = static_cast<uint32_t>(ns.count());
        mPcloudMsg.header.stamp.sec = timeSec;
        mPcloudMsg.header.stamp.nanosec = timeNsec;

        mPcloudMsg.data.clear();
        // mPcloudMsg.data.resize(mPcloudMsg.height * mPcloudMsg.width * 4 * 3);

        for (int i = 0; i < mPcloudMsg.width; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mPcloudMsg.height; ++j)
            {
                float tempX = 9.5;
                uint8_t* x = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&tempX);
                float tempY = i - 1.;
                uint8_t* y = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&tempY);
                float tempZ = j;
                uint8_t* z = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&tempZ);

                mPcloudMsg.data.insert(mPcloudMsg.data.end(), x, x + 4);
                mPcloudMsg.data.insert(mPcloudMsg.data.end(), y, y + 4);
                mPcloudMsg.data.insert(mPcloudMsg.data.end(), z, z + 4);
            }
        }
        /*std::cout << "pcloud size : " << mPcloudMsg.data.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Pcloud data : " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < mPcloudMsg.data.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << std::hex << (int)mPcloudMsg.data[i];
            if (i % 4 == 0)
                std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;*/

        mFrameCounter++;
        mPublisher->publish(mPcloudMsg);
    }
    uint64_t mFrameCounter = 0;
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr mTimer;
    sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 mPcloudMsg;
    rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr mPublisher;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<TestPcloud2Pub>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

I displayed the content of the message with

```
ros2 topic echo /test_pcloud
```

and the content seems fine to me.

Does anyone have any clue on the subject? How do I do to debug it when the error outputed i 'Unknown' ?

Thansk for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your fixed frame?

I see you are changing the frame_id every time. I am thinking that without proper connection between your pointcloud frame and rviz fixed frame, it is not able to visualize your message. Please try with a constant frame_id like "laser" and make sure you are viewing it in "laser" frame or another connected frame

Comment: Yes that was the problem ! by setting the frame_id to "Laser" I was able to view it in rviz, thanks !